# How can I make a real fullscreen on a galaxy s10

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen, samsung

[PICTURE of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKc4.png)
I observed that when you fullscreen a div on a galaxy s10 on chrome, because of the camera, there is a blank space. I suppose there is some sort of safe space so the content can be fully displayed...

I tried searching on the fullscreen mdn docs but found nothing about that specific issue.

Is there a way I can make my div take the whole screen including that black area or maybe choose a color ?
Here is how I fullscreen my div right now:

```
// fullscreen btn
document.querySelector(".fullscreen").onclick = function(){
    if (window.innerHeight == screen.height) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".app").requestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

and here is the div's and button's css :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.app{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: crimson;
}
.fullscreen{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see is it possible to get a look at your HTML file so that I can test it out on my computer to understand the issue better?

But if your saying that the div should take up the entire screen then try

```
.fullscreen{
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: burlywood;
}
```

Sorry if I'm wrong. If it doesn't work then consider giving me a look at the HTML file.

Comment: My issue here is that, on android phones having a camera directly on the screen, the space between the camera and the screen is blank (only when you enable fullscreen), I'm adding a screen shot to the question.

Comment: there is all the code in my question; only missing part is two divs, <div class="app"></div><div class="fullscreen"></div>

Comment: I see... sorry I don't know much about phones but you can join this discord community and ask them. Here: https://discord.gg/SdyFK7UG